# Facebook Change from Profile into an Artist Page -> Now all Friends lost

Tags: facebook, friends

I changed my Facebook profile with 1,300 Friends into a Facebook Page because I am a music artist. Facebook said only my friends and the profile picture would be in the Page.

Now that I have changed it, the problem now is that I have 0 likes and all the 1,300 people who listen to my music are lost.

How can I solve that problem? Did anyone have same experiences?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard about any possibility of changing regular Facebook profile into Facebook Page. You can always create a new Facebook Page once you're logged in to your regular (human) profile. Or you're forced to create a presonal profile, when you don't have one and want to have a Facebook Page. But to *convert* personal (private) profile into business Facebook Page... Is it possible at all?

This seems to be impossible, especially, if you take a strong naming politics Facebook has (no fake-name profiles, no Pages instead of profiles or without profiles, no names or profiles suggesting a product, event or campaign, not a real person).

Are you really sure, that you managed to convert a regular Facebook profile (which, according to Facebook regulations, should always represent a real person, not a business) into Facebook Page (which should always represent a business)?

And, to answer your question. You should always be able to conctact Facebook stuff to revert your operation or eventually you can always contact your friends and ask them to like your Page, just like they did to your regular profile.

But once again, either I don't understand you or you provided not enough detail or you're claiming, that you did something, that is impossible.